# Laravel 5.1 sync method with multiple attributes as primary

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5.1

I am using sync (on many to many) method in laravel 5.1 to add relational info to a user in DB.

My Table is

User-:

- id(pk)
- name
- email

tags-:

- id(pk)
- name
- slug

user_tags_mapping-:

- user_id
- tags_id
- function
- count

the relationship i have defined in between is a many to many

```
return $this->belongsToMany(
        tags::class, 'user_tags_mapping',
        'user_id', 'tags_id')->withPivot('function', 'count');
```

Now i am using sync to insert value into this table like

```
$user->tags()->sync([tags_id => [function, count]]);
```

Now my problem is that when i use the same tags_id with different function the sync detaches the older value as the tags_id already exist.

Is There a way where i can use tags_id and function both as the parameters to sync to the table where function is a string value.

I have already defined all the three parameter as primary inside the migration script, but it still didn't work.

Comment: I think this situation can be resolved using attach with a where clause.. Though i dont find it to be an appealing way to do it.